# Managing a Java and Shell script development in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

For my development project I am having to use Java jars and Shell script along with config files.

In eclipse currently I am just developing the Java jar applicaiton and then exporting it into a seperate folder where my Shell script is and other files.

Then I FTP this folder into server directory.

However I am running into problems where my shell script or java version are not the same.

Is there any way for me to just package it all into one eclipse project and export it as the following

**My Project**

- shell script.sh
- myappplication,jar
- myconfig.cfg
- archive folder

I tried putting it all in my SRC folder but all that I get out is a jar file from exporting the project.

Any suggestions welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using either [Ant](http://ant.apache.org) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), both of which are well-integrated into Eclipse (Maven is integrated by default in the latest release).

Depending on your project, it's possible Maven (which is a build lifecycle management system) is overkill, but check it out and see how it might aid your build process.

Using Ant would allow you to create a process which would gather your files together and transfer them to your remote system.

You can also check out [ShellEd](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/shelled/) for building shell scripts in Eclipse.  I've found it somewhat hit-or-miss, but it does allow me to stay in one IDE for most of my work.